# Model.Finder<I, T> Deperecated Play! 2.4

Tags: java, model-view-controller, playframework, ebean

I am building an application using the latest version of Play!. When defining a Finder( as in Model.Finder) my IDE gives me a warning Finder is deprecated. I can't find any information in the documentation about Model.Finder being deprecated of any alternative to using it. Has anyone experienced a similar issue and know of an alternative?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

According to [github](https://github.com/ebean-orm/avaje-ebeanorm/blob/master/src/main/java/com/avaje/ebean/Model.java#L277) `Model.Finder` is not deprecated, but one of its constructors:

```
/**
 * @deprecated
 */
public Finder(Class<I> idType, Class<T> type) {
  super(null, type);
}
```

Make sure you use correct constructor, pointed out by @biesior:

```
public static Finder<Long, Foo> find = new Finder<>(Foo.class);
```

Answer (score 18):

Use `Model.Finder<T>` like:

```
public static Finder<Long, Foo> find = new Finder<>(Foo.class);
```

instead of

```
public static Finder<Long, Foo> find = new Finder<>(Long.class, Foo.class);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try This

```
 public static Finder<Long, Foo> find = new Finder<>(Foo.class);
```